# MySQL Matching datetime with datetime-range takes forever

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, range

I have two tables on a MySQL-Server(InnoDB).
Both have a datetime-field and contain a measurements in each row.
Measurements in table A were taken every minute, measurements in table B every second.

Now I want to select the Min() of the measurements in table B that were taken +/- 30 seconds around measurement in table A and display it with the measurement from table A.

When I look for EQUAL timecodes, the query finishes in about a second.

But when I try to select them with a statement like:

```
SELECT min(tableB.measurement),tableA.* 
FROM tableA,tableB
WHERE tableA.timecode BETWEEN DATE_SUB(tableB.timecode,INTERVAL 30 SECOND) and  DATE_ADD(tableB.timecode,INTERVAL 30 SECOND)
GROUP BY tableA.timecode;
```

then the query runs forever (or at least until it hit's the timeout of MySQL Workbench, which I set to over an hour)

So the result of data like

```
table A
|timecode|measurement|
|15:00:30|    5      |
|15:10:30|    6      |

table B
|timecode|measurement|
|15:00:29|    105    |
|15:00:31|    56     |
|15:10:28|    25     |
|15:10:32|    16     |
```

should result in s.th like

```
|min(tableB.measurement)| timecode  |  measurement|
|       56              | 15:00:30  |      5      |
|       16              | 15:10:30  |      6      |
```

I actually misused SQL to handle big sets of tabular data(that I may not change). I know that this is not what you should do, but I found no other option to cope with this 15 million row-dataset...
Both datetime-fields have an index BTW...

Hoping for help,
Robert

Here's the EXPLAIN on the suggested query:

```
 id   select_type   table   partitions   type   possible_keys   key   key_len   ref   rows   filtered   Extra 
 1   PRIMARY         a         ALL           125953   100.00   
 2   DEPENDENT  SUBQUERY   b     ALL   idx_xc_timecode_trans,idx_xc_timecode_trans_measurement         15755656   11.11   
Range  checked  for  each  record  (index  map:  0x60)
```

Update:
The visual EXPLAIN in SQL Workbench just showed that the cost of s.th like

```
select * where tableA.timecode = tableB.timecode
```

is ~160.000

whereas s.th like

```
select * where tableA.timecode  between DATE_SUB( tableB.timecode, interval 30 second) and DATE_ADD(tableB.timecode, interval 30 second)
```

is ~99.600.000.000!!!

So does this mean that's a task which is likely not doable like this? Is that such a "uncommon" Query (in terms of "that's not what a DBMS was made for")?

Comment: I'm not certain, but the fact that your WHERE condition requires a calculation applied to data values may cause an entire table scan. Consider running an EXPLAIN query using your SQL there and see if the results can tell you anything about how it's being optimized

Comment: Pls share what indexes you have in the 2 tables, what fields these indexes have, and also share the output of the explain.

Comment: Are you missing a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Scrum Meister: Yep, just realized and and added it. Had it in the real query, with no change btw..

Comment: Why does timecode 15:00:30 show `min(tableB.timecode)=56` and not `min(tableB.timecode)=105`? 15:00:29 is +/- 30 seconds

Comment: @Shadow: There are individual indices on the datetime fields... Apart there are other indices for other fields. Are the others of importance here?

Comment: @Scrum Meister: Sorry, I messed it up. Should be min(tableB.measurement) of course... Thanks

Comment: According to the explain no indexes are used for the subquery. Try to use force index in the subquery. Also consider adding a multi column index on timecode, measurement fields.

Comment: @Shadow: This could be it, I'll try

Comment: Did you use the `BETWEEN` version initially, or the `<` and `>` version?

Comment: I tried both...

Comment: I expected the latter to be sargable.

Comment: In terms of calculated cost there's no difference...

Answer (score 0):

As long as `tableB.measurement` is indexed, the following query should work:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT b.measurement
        FROM tableB b
        WHERE b.timecode BETWEEN a.timecode - INTERVAL 30 SECOND
          AND a.timecode + INTERVAL 30 SECOND
        ORDER BY b.timecode
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS MinB,
     a.timecode,
     a.measurement
FROM tableA a
/*GROUP BY a.timecode*/
```

## Update

Looks like you want `MIN(b.measurement)` and not `MIN(b.timecode)`, so the query can be simplified:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT MIN(b.measurement)
        FROM tableB b
        WHERE b.timecode BETWEEN a.timecode - INTERVAL 30 SECOND
          AND a.timecode + INTERVAL 30 SECOND
    ) AS MinB,
     a.timecode,
     a.measurement
FROM tableA a
```

Comment: If there are duplicate timecode values in tableA, that would mean measurement is not functionally dependent on timecode, therefore your version of group by would fail under only full group by sql mode.

Comment: OK, the query is running, but it doesn't look so different from the situation before... Already two mins...

Comment: @RobertL. How many records does table A have? Please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT (`

Comment: @Scrum Meister: Table A has ~100.000, table B has 15 million...
Also created a table with a partial copy (only 10.000 records) without success

Answer (score 0):

You are adding or subtracting to the timecode datetime value in TableB, but are not specifying the INTERVAL.

```
SELECT min(tableB.timecode),tableA.* 
FROM tableA,tableB
WHERE tableA.timecode < DATE_ADD(tableB.timecode, + INTERVAL 30 SECOND) and tableA.timecode > DATE_ADD(tableB.timecode, INTERVAL -30 SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this out, but rounding the timecode to the nearest minute in a subquery and joining just on timecode might perform nicely:

```
SELECT b.measurement,tableA.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timecode)/60)) * 60 as timecode
            ,MIN(measurement) as measurement
      FROM tableB
      GROUP BY SEC_TO_TIME((ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timecode)/60)) * 60
      )b
 ON a.timecode = b.timecode
```

Since rounding won't do, you could check to see if `TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,a.timecode,b.timecode)` performs better than your current join:

```
SELECT min(b.measurement),a.timecode,a.measurement
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
 ON ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,a.timecode,b.timecode)) < 30
GROUP BY a.timecode,a.measurement;
```

Comment: Good idea, but the problem is that for example for timecode 15:30:25 I need everything precisely matched from 15:29:55 to 15:30:55.

Comment: @RobertL. Have you already tried `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`? Updated since rounding won't work.